# How to switch languages on login and lock screens?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, login-screen, input-language

I have configured <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch languages in Ubuntu. Unfortunately, this combination doesn't work on neither login screen nor lock screens.

How to switch languages on login and lock screens?

Comment: is it gdm or default lightdm?

Comment: I have tried it in Ubuntu 18.04 with default gdm, it is working as expected. to check this in lightdm.. please confirm whether you are using default lightdm in your Ubuntu 16.04?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/scOOv.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEnyQ.gi

Comment: Hi.. your question is 0nly about switching or switching the languages on login and lockscreenwith the shortcut key combo that you used in your Desktop Environment??

Comment: How does your login screen look like - is it LightDM [as on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvRcA.png)?